# How to insert a record in mysql even the key is missing

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table like this:

```
id  ctr
A    1
```

I'd like to insert a row of id A and update ctr to 2
The new value of ctr which is 2 is based on the previous value  increased by 1.
The table would look like this.

```
id   ctr
A     1
A     2
```

Now I'd like to insert another row of id B. But since B does not exist in the table it will have a counter initialized to 1. So the table will look like below.

```
id   ctr
A     1
A     2
B     1
```

Is there a way to do this in one sql statement? (I prefer mysql)
Thanks a lot.

edited:
Actually the table is very simple. the actual table would look like this:

```
id   amt balance  ctr
A    100   100     1
A    150   250     2
B    50    50      1
```

As with the ctr the balance is amt+the previous balance.
It is all inserts and no updates. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try to use IF and CASE statement of MySQL.

Comment: I already tried coalesce, ifnull and if . There was no error only null values in balance and ctr. I will try the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the primary key on `id` with `ctr`, and set the `ctr` auto-increment.

So every time you insert a record with `id = A`, the ctr will automatically increase.

```sql
`ctr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ctr`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE( MAX(ID)+1, 1 )` in order to initialize the `INSERT Statement` for a non-existing letter's ID as

```
SET @ctr = 'B';

INSERT INTO tab 
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID)+1,1),@ctr FROM tab WHERE ctr = @ctr
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=21b727f46e87dbe8ef34cee8f3d3d6fa)</kbd>

**even** for the cases **the unique key does not exist**, *otherwise* using

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ... FROM ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

would fit better to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can express in one query as as:

```
insert into t (id, ctr)
    select id, coalesce(max(ctr) + 1, 0)
    from (select 'a' as id union all
          select 'b' as id
         ) x left join
         t
         using (id)
    group by id;
```